# reload page if the ajax data is true

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I have some button on the page and when user click on it something happen in the background and send back confirmation as `True` in the following form `{ 'foo': true }`. It works for now but now I need to reload page if the foo is true. Code below sent request and background job is executed, confirmation is received and stored in the `bar` but page reload doesn't work. Also I need this working in all browsers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myButton').bind('click', function () {
        $.get("/foo/func/", function(data) {
            bar=data.foo;
            window.location.reload();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use on method() and use the if condition to check the condition

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myButton').on('click', function () {
        $.get("/foo/func/", function(data) {
            var bar=data.foo;
            if(bar)
           {
              window.location.reload(true);
           }
        });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
 var bar=data.foo;
 if(bar==true) 
 // if above does not work then
 // if(bar=="true") 
 {
   window.location.reload(true);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Ankush ` bar==true ` do the job